how to use @use in scss with a wildcard?
In my React app, I use SCSS and utilize "@use as" in many places. I use the application to present various styles, and the HTML/React structure remains identical.
for example:
@use "../../../styles/dog/style" as dog;
@use "../../../styles/cat/style" as cat;
...

.input{
    &_dog{
        @include dog.input_container;
    }
  &_cat{
        @include cat.input_container;
    }
}

I do not want to open each scss file, if i want to add a new style, like "fish" "rabbit".
i'd like to have a solution like:

in another file: const animals = [dog, cat, fish];
...

@import * as animals from "./animals"

animals.foreach(@use "../../../sytles/´${animal}/style" as animal

@each input{
    &_#animal{
      @include #animal.input_container;
}
}

I've read, the is no wildcard support in SCSS, but is there any other option to automate that?
